# Filter for nested objects to return all children elements

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have a filter that is on `ng-repeat` and compares strings of all objects (including nested ones) to a search string. If the search string is found in the object, it returns true.

I'm looking for a way to extend this functionality so that when the search string matches with a string in the object, the filter will return true for that object and will return true for all nested objects in the matching object (this is a tree view, I'm searching for a node and want to show all children nodes when matched).

How would I do that?

My filter looks like this:

```
 .filter('deepFilter', function ($filter) {
    return function(text) {
       return function (value) {
            if(text && text.length > 0) {
              var searchTerm = text;
              if (angular.isObject(value)) {
                  var found = false;
                  angular.forEach(value, function(v) {
                      found = found || $filter('deepFilter')(searchTerm)(v);
                  });
                  return found;

              } else if (angular.isString(value)) {
                  if (value.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {
                      return true;
                  } else {
                      return false;
                  }
              }
            } else {
              return true;
            }
        };
     };
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is by using a function in the `isString` part of the filter, and iterating over the collection. If I find the object, I look for it's children using a recursive function and set a `visibleAsAChild` property for these. Then, I've added a condition in the `isObject` evaluation to return `true` for these object that have `visibleAsAChild` prop. 
I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way to do it, but it certainly works.

```
.filter('deepFilter', function ($filter) {
var currentObject;
var setChildrenToVisible = function(node) {
  angular.forEach(node.nodes, function(node) {
    if(node.nodes) {
      setChildrenToVisible(node);
    }
    node.visibleAsAChild = true;
  });
};
var lookupChildren = function(o, value) {
  // console.log(o);
  angular.forEach(o.nodes, function(node) {
    if (node.name === value) {
      setChildrenToVisible(node);
    }
  });
};

return function(text) {

   return function (value) {

        if(text && text.length > 0) {
          var searchTerm = text;
          if (angular.isObject(value)) {
              var found = false;
              angular.forEach(value, function(v) {
                found = found || $filter('deepFilter')(searchTerm)(v);
              });
              if(found && value.hasOwnProperty('id')) {
                currentObject = value;
              }
              if(value.hasOwnProperty('id') && value.visibleAsAChild) {
                return true;
              }
              return found;

          } else if (angular.isString(value)) {
              if (value.indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1) {
                if(currentObject){
                  lookupChildren(currentObject, value);
                }
                  return true;
              } else {
                  return false;
              }
          }
        } else {
          return true;
        }
    };
 };
```